# What is the expected behavior of Agg functions with SELECT * (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

What would you expect to get when running -

```
select *, max(col1) from table1;
```

What would you expect to get

1. only the row with the max(col1)
2. all rows with the max(col1) value next to them

Is this different between different DBs?

Comment: An error... (Column table1.col1 not referenced in GROUP BY clause.)

Comment: Read the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html): It explains how mySQL extends the group by clause which would behave differently than other RDBMS systems; unless of course you've disabled this feature which is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one row with the maximum value of `col1`, then use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
order by col1 desc
limit 1;
```

In MySQL, your query would return one row with indeterminate values for all the columns represented by `*` with the maximum value of `col1`.  In other databases, it would return an error.